# Firebase Cloud Messaging Web Service Worker not handling click events on Notifications

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the following service worker:

```
//firebase-messaging-sw.js
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.19.1/firebase-app-compat.js")
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.19.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js")



const firebaseConfig = {
    //REDACTED
  };

// Initialize Firebase
const app =firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging(app);

// DEBUG ONLY: Explore the notification payload
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  });
```

Background Notifications work well, however, according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#setting_notification_options_in_the_send_request) populating the "fcm_options.link" parameter should open the link in a browser on Notification click. This is not working.

I can confirm that the service worker is receiving all the data in the Notification Payload:

```
//Notification Payload
{
    "from": "294754226734",
    "messageId": "539b6fe5-6b0c-47dc-baca-1ce243a20e4f",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Bridge Notification",
        "body": "Closure from 3:15 PM to 4:15 PM today (03/26/2023)",
        "icon": "https://app.com/white_sm.png"
    },
    "fcmOptions": {
        "link": "https://app.com"
    }
}
```

Oddly enough, creating my own listener in the service worker works in creating the Notification onclick functionality:

```
//firebase-messaging-sw.js
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
    event.notification.close();
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] notification Event Listener Triggered ',  event);

    const pathname = event.notification?.data?.FCM_MSG?.notification?.click_action
    if (!pathname) return
    const url = new URL(pathname, self.location.origin).href

    event.waitUntil(
        self.clients
            .matchAll({ type: 'window', includeUncontrolled: true })
            .then((clientsArr) => {
                const hadWindowToFocus = clientsArr.some((windowClient) =>
                    windowClient.url === url ? (windowClient.focus(), true) : false
                )

                if (!hadWindowToFocus)
                    self.clients
                        .openWindow(url)
                        .then((windowClient) =>
                            windowClient ? windowClient.focus() : null
                        )
            })
    )
})


importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.19.1/firebase-app-compat.js")
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.19.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js")


const firebaseConfig = {
    //REDACTED
  };

// Initialize Firebase
const app =firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging(app);

// DEBUG ONLY: Explore the notification payload
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  });
```

Wondering if anyone has any idea of what I am doing wrong or is this a bug.

Comment: Using  'FirebaseAdmin.Messaging' Nuget package (net6.0) to create the Notifications server side.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out by looking at the [service worker SDK source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/37de4d015c9d0ed5341519533eb753b58ecbcff0/packages/messaging/src/listeners/sw-listeners.ts#L137). The 'fcmOptions.link' MUST have the same host as the service worker registration host.

**Example:**

Service Worker host: https://www.app.com/

fcmOptions.link that **will work**: https://www.app.com/pageOne

fcmOptions.link that **will NOT work**: https://www.google.com

Answer (score -1):

According to documentation [cloud-messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) the **'click_action'** field should be set to the URL that should be opened when the notification is clicked. You have used **'link'** instead of **'click_action'** try to change it.

Comment: It looks like the fcmOptions object is supported in version 9 of the js SDK, see the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/messaging_sw.fcmoptions#fcmoptionslink

Comment: 'click_action' doesn't seem to be a property of Web Notifications (it exists on Android-specific notifications). For Web Notifications the documentation state that fcmOptions.link should be used. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.webpushfcmoptions.md#webpushfcmoptionslink